# What are the most prominent features of Yamagata-ben?

Tags: dialects

I'll be visiting Yamagata City soon and would like to ask:

- as an armchair linguist what features of the local dialect to look out for?
- what are some common words, phrases, pronunciation differences that I could try to effect to make a nice impression on the locals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't help you with first-hand knowledge, but you can start by looking [here](http://www.jvnet.or.jp/~badz9005/tendo/hougen.htm). Some of the comparisons (like 「んだ」 instead of 「そうです」) seems to be part of the standard Touhoku-ben fare.

### Edit

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%81), there's some good variety for the expression I quoted (「んだ」) in its formal version (which is equivalent to 「そうです」). In Murayama, for instance, it would be 「んだず」,「んだべした」or「んだずにゃー」, while in Shinjou it would be 「んだじゅー」or 「んだにゃー」. I can't find many explanations in that article, but it seems like quite a variety.

Comment: Now that I'm in Yamagata City I can confirm the first localism I was taught when I asked this question was indeed "んだ" (nda).